# git blame throws a bad revision error with the -L <n,m> option

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

One of the `git blame` options processes a line range. The manual says:

> -L  Process only line range n,m, counting from 1

Now, I have a file that has over 100 lines. When I run `git blame -L 5,15 myFile.txt`, git complains:

> fatal: bad revision '15'

Interestingly, git does not complain when I run `git blame -L 5 myFile.txt`.

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe silly question, but are you sure you have no extra space after that comma.

Comment: Solved. The error occurs in PowerShell but not in Command Prompt. Somehow, PowerShell is injecting a space after the comma.

Comment: That error message should occur less often with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755231/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command looks correct in that case.

I have checked that problem with my composer.json file, and it's working well. When I try to access more lines than are inside the file, I get an error "file composer.json has only 87 lines".

You get this error only if you have a space before the second value.

```
git blame -L 10, 200 composer.json 

fatal: bad revision '200'
```

So I think that's the problem.

Note that PowerShell and/or Posh-Git might inject a space after the comma. Try using the command prompt.

Comment: The problem is that PowerShell injects a space after the comma. There is no error when I run the same command in a normal command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

if you quote the lines it will work

```
git blame -L '10,200' composer.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: with git 2.19 (Q3 2018), parsing of `-L[<N>][,[<M>]]` parameters "`git blame`" and "`git log`" take has been tweaked.

That should avoid certain case of `fatal: bad revision '15'`, especially when the file has less than 15 lines:

See [commit 7f81c00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f81c00f3b1bd45c2954b18550b8e351651f72f3), [commit 96cfa94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96cfa94e68cfbe9942e230ae18b35eaf1ca30f99) (15 Jun 2018) by [Isabella Stephens (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6566a91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6566a917d8a8d3070b5fdc94fbe5f6d68a4d656b), 02 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `blame`: prevent error if range ends past end of file
>
> If the `-L` option is used to specify a line range in `git blame`, and the
>   end of the range is past the end of the file, git will fail with a fatal
>   error. 
>   **This commit prevents such behavior - instead we display the blame
>   for existing lines within the specified range**.
>
> This commit also fixes two corner cases.
>
> - Blaming `-L n,-(n+1)` now blames the first `n` lines of a file *rather than from `n` to the end of the file*.
> - Blaming `-L ,-n` will be treated as `-L 1,-n` and **blame the first line of
>     the file, rather than blaming the whole file**.